# javascript / IE 6/7: check if within an iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page which needs to check whether it is contained within an iframe or not in effect whether the page is the top page.

I tried doing this: `if(window == window.parent)` and it works for Opera, FF, and Chrome but not for IE. is there some trick in IE I should use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (top != self)
{
    // I'm in an iframe
}
```

Comment: … or some other kind of frame.

Comment: +1 I'm using this in a Iframe facebook app that can also be accessed externally (both use FB Connect).  Since try { window.parent.location } .. causes very different errors in each browser (Chrome shows the dead computer error), I have no idea why this method should be allowed to work.